# Highlight #pragma in code listing using minted

Tags: beamer, highlighting, minted

I'm going to give a talk on OpenMP soon and I'm currently preparing my `beamer` slides. Since a lot of the OpenMP magic happens inside of `#pragma` instructions, I'd like to highlight those in some bright color (but still highlight the rest of the code, too). I'm using the `minted` package for code listings. Currently, the code below will result in the `#include` statements and the `#pragma` line being highlighted in the same yellowish color. Let's say I want the `#pragma omp parallel` in bright red while keeping everything else as is.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}
\newminted{c}{fontsize=\footnotesize,bgcolor=lightgray}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{ccode}
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
#pragma omp parallel
    {
        int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        printf("Hello from thread %d\n", tid);
    }
    return 0;
}
\end{ccode}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Compile with `xelatex -shell-escape test.tex`. Result:

[image]

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You're absolutely right, of course. Done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update 2017-01-11: This no longer works with recent versions of `minted`. There is a [more recent, similar solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/348144/10742) that currently does work.**

It's possible to do this by modifying the underlying Pygments style macros. This will work with recent versions of `minted`, but since it is modifying the internals, it may not always work in the future. You would need to replace the `default` in `\PYGdefault` with a different style name if you want to use a different highlighting style. Also, if you want to use a different style, you would need to have a `\usemintedstyle` in the preamble.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\newminted{c}{fontsize=\footnotesize,bgcolor=lightgray}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\originalpyg\PYGdefault
  \renewcommand{\PYGdefault}[2]{%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{c+cp}%
     {\IfBeginWith{#2}{\PYGZsh{}pragma}%
       {\originalpyg{#1}{\color{red}{#2}}}%
       {\originalpyg{#1}{#2}}}%
     {\originalpyg{#1}{#2}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{ccode}
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
#pragma omp parallel
    {
        int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        printf("Hello from thread %d\n", tid);
    }
    return 0;
}
\end{ccode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to figure this out, and for creating such a powerful package in the first place.