# minted and different coloured pragmas

Tags: minted, pygments

I try to see if is possible to use minted to colour #pragma statements differently based on what comes after the pragma, omp, acc.

I am aware of this 
[Highlight #pragma in code listing using minted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304963/highlight-pragma-in-code-listing-using-minted)
but this is not fit for my purpose. I have close to little knowledge on how pygmentize works, so any thoughts will be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{shellesc}
\usepackage{minted}
\newminted{c}{fontsize=\footnotesize,bgcolor=lightgray}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\originalpyg\PYGdefault
  \renewcommand{\PYGdefault}[2]{%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{c+cp}%
     {\IfBeginWith{#2}{\PYGZsh{}pragma}%
       {\originalpyg{#1}{\color{red}{#2}}}%
       {\originalpyg{#1}{#2}}}%
     {\originalpyg{#1}{#2}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{ccode}
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
    printf("Hello from thread %d\n", tid);
  }
  #pragma acc parallel
  {
    printf("Hello from acc\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
\end{ccode}
\end{document}
```

to build

```
lualatex -shell-escape color.tex
```

I have already tried the obvious, adding omp after pragma but seems somehow only pragma is passed to the string.

what will be nice to achieve is #pragma omp and #pragma acc to be coloured differently

Alin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want.  Just replace what you currently have in the preamble.

```
\makeatletter
\minted@checkstyle{default}
\let\originalpyg\PYGdefault
\newcommand{\activespace}{\FV@Space}
\renewcommand{\PYGdefault}[2]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{c+cp}%
   {\IfBeginWith{#2}{\FancyVerbBreakStart\PYGZsh{}pragma\activespace omp}%
     {\originalpyg{#1}{\color{red}{#2}}}%
     {\IfBeginWith{#2}{\FancyVerbBreakStart\PYGZsh{}pragma\activespace acc}%
       {\originalpyg{#1}{\color{green}{#2}}}%
       {\originalpyg{#1}{#2}}}}%
   {\originalpyg{#1}{#2}}%
}%
\makeatother
```

The old, linked example no longer works with current versions of `minted`. And since this new code is also hacking the internals, it may also break in the future.

The `\minted@checkstyle{default}` is required to make sure that the default style, with `\PYGdefault`, exists.  In recent versions of `minted`, the styles are only created within commands/environments immediately before use, rather than at the end of the preamble.  `\minted@checkstyle` forces style definition immediately.

The `\activespace` is required to make the comparison recognize spaces, since spaces are treated specially in verbatim contexts defined using `fancyvrb`.

The `\FancyVerbBreakStart` is inserted at the start of the second argument of every `\PYG<style>` command by the `fvextra` package. It makes line breaking possible.

Comment: thank you @g-poore very much, does indeed what I need and open posibilities for more. tested it with what looks like version 2.4.1 of minted.