# Keyword lists for OpenMP and OpenACC for listings

Tags: listings, programming

Has anybody produced a dialect for the C, C++, and Fortran languages in the listings package to highlight OpenMP and OpenACC directives in code that include these pragmas (C/C++) or sentinels (Fortran)?

I would be happy to start writing one from scratch too, if nobody has ever done that, but I'm a noob when it comes to LaTeX programming or writing a `.sty` file.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304963/highlight-pragma-in-code-listing-using-minted

Comment: That's unfortunately only for C/C++ and not for Fortran.